# HTTP 500 when publishing .net core 2.0 website

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, azure, asp.net-core

When publishing a .net core 2.0 website to Azure or to a local IIS, the publish process passes, but when opening the site i receive : `HTTP ERROR 500`.

To see the real error behind, i modified the web.config of the published site to:

```
   <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\OurWebApp.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="true" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout">
     <environmentVariables>
        <environmentVariable name="ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT" value="Development" />
      </environmentVariables>
  </aspNetCore>
```

The error behind is:

```
InvalidOperationException: No service for type 'Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore.JavaScriptSnippet' has been registered.
```

Answer (score 2):

The solution was to remove the following from layout pages like _Layout.cshtml:

```
@inject Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore.JavaScriptSnippet JavaScriptSnippet
```

and

```
@Html.Raw(JavaScriptSnippet.FullScript)
```

Then publish again